# how to edit CMakeLists.txt with my program using package "create_node"?

Tags: ros, catkin, include, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

my program will use the package: create_node,
my cpp file: #include <create_mode/TurtlebotSebsorState.h>

I think I need edit CMakeLists.txt to let catkin know i will use it
but i don't know what place I need write it and what should I write

is it in #Build# tag? or other place ?

===================

big thanks tbh for point the typo and help me :)
after I tried add create_node to find_package and catkin_package like this:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS create_node roscpp rospy std_msgs)

catkin_package(
   INCLUDE_DIRS include
   CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs create_node)
```

when I use command catkin_make , it's the error message:

```
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'bump_sensor'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(bump_sensor)
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package create_node.

  Set create_node_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file
  for create_node.  The file will have one of the following names:

    create_nodeConfig.cmake
    create_node-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  bump_sensor/CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)


-- +++ processing catkin package: 'movement'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(movement)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

is it means can not find the package create_node?
or my CMakeLists.txt still not complete ? :/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67288/how-to-edit-cmakelists.txt-with-my-program-using-package-%22create_node%22-?/) by [n](https://answers.ros.org/users/5415/n/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-07-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-07-15**:
What version of `create_node` are you using? How did you install it? The master branch of https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_create still uses rosbuild. The hydro-devel branch appears to use catkin.

**Comment by [n](https://answers.ros.org/users/5415/n/) on 2013-07-28**:
I am using groovy version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A catkin package may not depend on a rosbuild one.

Since you are using Groovy, and that create_node release still uses rosbuild, your catkin package cannot refer to it. In Hydro that will probably work. Meanwhile, you'll need to maintain your program in a rosbuild package.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [n](https://answers.ros.org/users/5415/n/) on 2013-07-29**:
i got it. thank you